# RSpec request test - sign in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to finish an RSpec request spec but I am running into a problem.

Can someone explain to me why this test below works as expected:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "RegisteredApplication", :type => :request do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "should create an application" do

    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    post "/registered_applications", registered_application: { name: "My new App", url: "www.newapp.test" }
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:found)
  end
end
```

But this test fails with the following error: Failure/Error: delete "/registered_applications/1"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method call for RegisteredApplication:0x007f950f19b850

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "RegisteredApplication", :type => :request do

  let(:app) { FactoryGirl.create(:registered_application) }
  let(:user) { app.user }

  it "should create an application" do

    login_as(user, :scope => :user)

    post "/registered_applications", registered_application: { name: "My new App", url: "www.newapp.test" }
  end
end
```

spec/factories/registered_applications.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :registered_application do
    name 'My newest application'
    url 'www.mynewestapp.test'
    user
  end
end
```

spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Jack Sparrow"
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "helloworld"
    password_confirmation "helloworld"
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

My RegisteredApplication model has `validates :user, presence: true`.  This is why I was creating a user with `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }`, signing that user in, and then manually entering the post request.  To try and keep things DRY I decided to set up a `user` association in my `registered_applications_spec.rb` factory and now I keep getting that error listed above.  Any ideas as to why the first test is passing and my second refactored test is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.  It turns out all I had to do was change:

`let(:app) { FactoryGirl.create(:registered_application) }`

to

`let(:any_other_name) { FactoryGirl.create(:registered_application) }`

Turns out the method `app` is used somewhere needed by Request specs.